# Using XAML Icons of Visual Studio 2022 Image Library

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-7.0

I am using the icons of `Visual Studio 2022 Image Library` in `xaml` format in a `ResourceDictionary`.
All I have to do then, is to give a key and I can use them as content in WPF controls:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Rectangle x:Key="ProcessIcon" Width="16 " Height="16">
        <Rectangle.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="canvas" Opacity="0" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="light-defaultgrey" Color="#212121" Opacity="1" />
        </Rectangle.Resources>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <DrawingBrush Stretch="None">
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource canvas}" Geometry="F1M16,16H0V0H16Z" />
                        </DrawingGroup>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource light-defaultgrey}" Geometry="F1M8,5V4H6.949a2.473,2.473,0,0,0-.365-.876l.745-.745-.707-.707-.745.745A2.469,2.469,0,0,0,5,2.051V1H4V2.051a2.469,2.469,0,0,0-.877.366l-.745-.745-.707.707.745.745A2.473,2.473,0,0,0,2.051,4H1V5H2.051a2.473,2.473,0,0,0,.365.876l-.745.745.707.707.745-.745A2.469,2.469,0,0,0,4,6.949V8H5V6.949a2.469,2.469,0,0,0,.877-.366l.745.745.707-.707-.745-.745A2.473,2.473,0,0,0,6.949,5ZM4.5,6A1.5,1.5,0,1,1,6,4.5,1.5,1.5,0,0,1,4.5,6Z" />
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource light-defaultgrey}" Geometry="F1M13.937,10.633a3.271,3.271,0,0,0-.1-.784l1.242-.514-.383-.924-1.244.515A3.314,3.314,0,0,0,12.34,7.819l.515-1.245-.923-.383-.515,1.242a3.007,3.007,0,0,0-1.568,0L9.335,6.191l-.924.383.515,1.245A3.311,3.311,0,0,0,7.819,8.926L6.575,8.411l-.383.924,1.241.514a3.007,3.007,0,0,0,0,1.568l-1.241.515.383.923,1.244-.515a3.314,3.314,0,0,0,1.107,1.108l-.515,1.243.924.383.514-1.241a2.983,2.983,0,0,0,1.569,0l.514,1.241.923-.383-.515-1.243a3.307,3.307,0,0,0,1.108-1.108l1.244.515.383-.923-1.242-.515A3.278,3.278,0,0,0,13.937,10.633Zm-5.608,0a2.3,2.3,0,1,1,2.3,2.305A2.307,2.307,0,0,1,8.329,10.633Z" />
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

```
<Button Command="{Binding ...}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{StaticResource ProcessIcon}" Margin="0 -5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Title" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

This works for one button only. When using the same icon on a second button, the first button shows the icon no more.

I found out, that this is because of the icon is a `FrameworkElement` and can have only one parent. The solution should be to mark it as `x:Shared=False`: [WPF: Can use StaticResource only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154572/wpf-can-use-staticresource-only-once)

But this does not work here, I don't know why. Because of `ResourceDictionary`? Because of the icon not being an image?

I don't know either, how to convert the `Rectangle` to an image. This is the xaml that came out of the Microsoft pack...

---

Update: based on [emoacht's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77113868/2477582), I was able to use it like that:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ...}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Background="{StaticResource ProcessIcon}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="5 0" />
        <TextBlock Text="Title" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <VisualBrush x:Key="ProcessIcon">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Rectangle Width="16 " Height="16">
                <Rectangle.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="canvas" Opacity="0" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="light-defaultgrey" Color="#212121" Opacity="1" />
                </Rectangle.Resources>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <DrawingBrush Stretch="None">
                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            <DrawingGroup>
                                <DrawingGroup>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource canvas}" Geometry="F1M16,16H0V0H16Z" />
                                </DrawingGroup>
                                <DrawingGroup>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource light-defaultgrey}" Geometry="F1M8,5V4H6.949a2.473,2.473,0,0,0-.365-.876l.745-.745-.707-.707-.745.745A2.469,2.469,0,0,0,5,2.051V1H4V2.051a2.469,2.469,0,0,0-.877.366l-.745-.745-.707.707.745.745A2.473,2.473,0,0,0,2.051,4H1V5H2.051a2.473,2.473,0,0,0,.365.876l-.745.745.707.707.745-.745A2.469,2.469,0,0,0,4,6.949V8H5V6.949a2.469,2.469,0,0,0,.877-.366l.745.745.707-.707-.745-.745A2.473,2.473,0,0,0,6.949,5ZM4.5,6A1.5,1.5,0,1,1,6,4.5,1.5,1.5,0,0,1,4.5,6Z" />
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource light-defaultgrey}" Geometry="F1M13.937,10.633a3.271,3.271,0,0,0-.1-.784l1.242-.514-.383-.924-1.244.515A3.314,3.314,0,0,0,12.34,7.819l.515-1.245-.923-.383-.515,1.242a3.007,3.007,0,0,0-1.568,0L9.335,6.191l-.924.383.515,1.245A3.311,3.311,0,0,0,7.819,8.926L6.575,8.411l-.383.924,1.241.514a3.007,3.007,0,0,0,0,1.568l-1.241.515.383.923,1.244-.515a3.314,3.314,0,0,0,1.107,1.108l-.515,1.243.924.383.514-1.241a2.983,2.983,0,0,0,1.569,0l.514,1.241.923-.383-.515-1.243a3.307,3.307,0,0,0,1.108-1.108l1.244.515.383-.923-1.242-.515A3.278,3.278,0,0,0,13.937,10.633Zm-5.608,0a2.3,2.3,0,1,1,2.3,2.305A2.307,2.307,0,0,1,8.329,10.633Z" />
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingGroup>
                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    </DrawingBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `VisualBrush` from any Visual including Rectangle and store it in Resources. Then you can use it like other Brush as icon image.

```xml
<VisualBrush x:Key="ProcessIcon">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
            <Rectangle.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="canvas" Opacity="0" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="light-defaultgrey" Color="#212121" Opacity="1" />
            </Rectangle.Resources>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <DrawingBrush Stretch="None">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup x:Name="canvas">
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource canvas}" Geometry="F1M16,16H0V0H16Z" />
                            </DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup x:Name="level_1">
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource light-defaultgrey}" Geometry="F1M8,5V4H6.949a2.473,2.473,0,0,0-.365-.876l.745-.745-.707-.707-.745.745A2.469,2.469,0,0,0,5,2.051V1H4V2.051a2.469,2.469,0,0,0-.877.366l-.745-.745-.707.707.745.745A2.473,2.473,0,0,0,2.051,4H1V5H2.051a2.473,2.473,0,0,0,.365.876l-.745.745.707.707.745-.745A2.469,2.469,0,0,0,4,6.949V8H5V6.949a2.469,2.469,0,0,0,.877-.366l.745.745.707-.707-.745-.745A2.473,2.473,0,0,0,6.949,5ZM4.5,6A1.5,1.5,0,1,1,6,4.5,1.5,1.5,0,0,1,4.5,6Z" />
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource light-defaultgrey}" Geometry="F1M13.937,10.633a3.271,3.271,0,0,0-.1-.784l1.242-.514-.383-.924-1.244.515A3.314,3.314,0,0,0,12.34,7.819l.515-1.245-.923-.383-.515,1.242a3.007,3.007,0,0,0-1.568,0L9.335,6.191l-.924.383.515,1.245A3.311,3.311,0,0,0,7.819,8.926L6.575,8.411l-.383.924,1.241.514a3.007,3.007,0,0,0,0,1.568l-1.241.515.383.923,1.244-.515a3.314,3.314,0,0,0,1.107,1.108l-.515,1.243.924.383.514-1.241a2.983,2.983,0,0,0,1.569,0l.514,1.241.923-.383-.515-1.243a3.307,3.307,0,0,0,1.108-1.108l1.244.515.383-.923-1.242-.515A3.278,3.278,0,0,0,13.937,10.633Zm-5.608,0a2.3,2.3,0,1,1,2.3,2.305A2.307,2.307,0,0,1,8.329,10.633Z" />
                            </DrawingGroup>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! Is using it via `Label` a valid approach? Are there other (more common?) ways to use it?

Comment: To show the icon image, a simple shape such as `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` will suffice. For example, `<Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="{StaticResource ProcessIcon}"/>`.  The question on what is common is opinion-based.